# Timer in Counter Mode using arduino mega 2560

Tags: timer, arduino, avr, atmega

i am using arduino mega 2560 and i wanted to use counter of timer 1 , i have given clock of 100 Hz on pin 11 for timer 1 counter, i have also configured the timer-1 register B  and set the CS(clock select) bits  but for some reason its not working. Below is my code, would be grateful if any one can point my mistake over here or modify the code to correct it or just give any suggestion. I have also attached the file.

```
int val;
void setup()
{
startCounting();
}

void loop()
{ 
  val =TCNT1;
  Serial.println(val);
}

void startCounting()  //Encoder FrequencyCounter Start
{
/*  Timer 1 would be used for frequency counter. Using event counter mode of timer.*/ 

TCNT1=0x00;          //Reset Timer 1 Counter.
TCCR1A=0x00;
TCCR1B=0x07;       // To set all pins CSn2,CSn1,CSn0 to use external clock source on Tn Pin. Clock on rising edge.
                                    //pin 11 for timer 1 will be used as an external clock.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you state and have CSn2:0 = 7 you are attempting to use external clock source. However the input pin in this mode is not OCnA (OC1A=pin 11) but rather Tn, which will then drive CLK(Tn) and increment TCNTn.

Unfortunately on the ArduinoMega only T0(D38) and T5(D47) are implemented on the board to headers. The rest T1,2,3 & 4 are not routed from the chip itself.

*!Don't mess with Timer0.* Core libraries use it.

You could try to move to Timer5 and use T5 on D47 as the 100Hz input.

Where if you are trying to create a frequency counter, I would suggest using the Input Capture. For an Example see [InputCapture.ino](https://gist.github.com/mpflaga/4404996)